# Readline sometimes works in iPython, sometimes doesn't

Tags: python, bash, ipython, readline

I cannot find a pattern to this but when I launch ipython from a Bash shell, sometimes I find that readline commands like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> work fine for moving to the front/back of a line. Sometimes, inexplicably, those commands just print **^a** or **^e** to the screen.

When that happens, how do I get readline back?

Comment: Pay attention and see if you notice a pattern.  Are you always start `python` the same way?  Can you get different behavior in two adjacent runs?  Are you sometimes starting the bare interpreter and other times loading in a file?

Comment: I always start from the shell prompt with a bare interpreter. I haven't tried two adjacent runs. I have been looking for a pattern, I swear.

Comment: I have experienced similar issues with certain key bindings suddenly stopping to work. This was probably a bug, as this stopped once I upgraded the ipython version.

Answer (score 0):

This force a `readline`:

```
$ rlwrap -a ipython
```

`iPython` (v.12) come with `readline` automatically for me.  You can make more check: file `~/.inputrc`, or is there `readline` before you call `iPython`.  Hope this help.

Comment: IPython talks to readline via the Python bindings. I don't know what effect using `rlwrap` as well will have.